# How to extract coins out of an image?

Tags: objective-c, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

So I want to segment and extract the coins out of the image and use them for other purposes. But I ran into problems extracting those coins out first. The background shouldn't be white all the time.

[image]

I've tried thresholding and find the contours, but it returns more contours than expected. What should I do?

```
cv::Mat coinpic, backgroundpic, diffpic, newpic, threshold;

cv::cvtColor([self cvMatFromUIImage:coins], coinpic, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

cv::threshold(coinpic, diffpic, 200, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv::THRESH_OTSU);

vector<vector<cv::Point>> contours;
vector<cv::Vec4i> hierarchy;

cv::findContours(diffpic, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

cout << contours.size() << endl;

return [self UIImageFromCVMat:diffpic];
```

The result I expect is like this following link: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.3/d3/db4/tutorial_py_watershed.html

Comment: Please add more context to your question. Can you share an example input image, in what conditions do you want a program to work...?

Comment: Add an example of the _input_ image you are using.

Comment: I have edited my post with an example of the input image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coins detection is the typical example where you (most probably) want to use Hough Transform for circles. It implemented in OpenCV and you can find several examples, for example [here](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/07/21/detecting-circles-images-using-opencv-hough-circles/) and [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.2/da/d53/tutorial_py_houghcircles.html) (these are in Python, but you can find many others)

You will probably get more (or not all) contours at the first attempt, to fix this you should play with param1 and param2 (see the opencv [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.2/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga47849c3be0d0406ad3ca45db65a25d2d))

Comment: But what if Hough Circle doesn't detect every coin in the image?